# How to refresh already upgraded Service Application Databases?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, administration, 2016, upgrade, sharepoint-on-prem

Here is the common scenario:

General task: upgrade old SP2013 environment to SP2016.

Service applications that need to be migrated:

- Managed Metadata
- Subscription Services
- Excel services
- SSS
- etc

Approach we used: We've just created new Service Applications that would point to the migrated databases. Like so:

```
$mms = New-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Name 'Managed Metadata Service Application' -ApplicationPool $applicationPool -DatabaseName 'Managed Metadata Service OLD SP 2013 DB'
New-SPMetadataServiceApplicationProxy -Name "Managed Metadata Service Application Proxy" -ServiceApplication $mms -DefaultProxyGroup
```

Long story short, all went well. The databases were upgraded. The Client tested the new environment and now we are ready for the cutover. During the testing period the old environment was actively used and now I need to migrate the databases one more time. Do a data refresh for all service applications

The question is: What is the best way to refresh the databases one more time? Do I delete all service applications and run the `New-***ServiceApplication` command one more time? or there is an easier "refresh" method?

Recreating the databases is not a hard task. I can do it, but I've been thinking if there is a "refresh/upgrade" method that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to migrate is to delete all of the Service Applications and then create new ones off of the newly restored databases.

Comment: Oh well, I'll do it this way then